# how to change url name while using resource route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Normally while using resource route for example like this:

```
Route::resource('somethings','SomethingsController' );
```

The url here which is displayed in browser in http://localhost:8000/somthings/create but what want is to display like this:

http://localhost:8000/somthings basically I dont want create in the url.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change URL while using `Route::resource()`. You'll need to define all routes manually:

```
Route::get('somethings', 'SomethingsController@createSomething');
```

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-localizing-resource-uris

> App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider

file, `boot` add the following;

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::resourceVerbs([
        'create' => 'oluştur',
        'edit' => 'düzenle',
    ]);
 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The page just stays empty

Answer (score -2):

To change route names in resource:

```
Route::resource('somethings', 'SomethingsController', [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'somethings.index',
        'store' => 'somethings.store',
        ...
    ]
]);
```

Comment: He is asking about changing the url and not the name